# Docker: Are Docker links deprecated?

Tags: linux, docker

When reading about linking containers together they now call it *legacy links* e.g. [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/).

[This article](https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/docker-networking/) claims `links` got deprecated in Docker 1.9, but the [release notes](https://docs.docker.com/v1.9/engine/misc/deprecated/) doesn't mention this and the [list of deprecated features](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/) doesn't mention it either.

**Question**

Why does Docker now call `links` for legacy links? And should I stop use them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Docker networking is being promoted as successor - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

> Before the Docker network feature, you could use the Docker link feature to allow containers to discover each other. With the introduction of Docker networks, containers can be discovered by its name automatically.

On whether you should stop using them - yes. The docker world is currently moving very fast, and links has been "legacy" for a few releases now.

Comment: If I see `link` being used in an online post then I know the info is most likely out of date. It's useful that way. Same goes for ADD instead of COPY in Dockerfiles, but to a lesser degree.

Comment: @Alkaline Are you saying COPY or ADD will possibly be deprecated as well?

Comment: @LF4, deprecation is not the case of ADD and COPY. The thing is that COPY should be used over ADD when you just need to copy files and not use the features of ADD (decompression, url downloading)

Answer (score 5):

well at least mentioned here by Docker official documentation:

> Warning: The --link flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. It
>   may eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue
>   using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to
>   facilitate communication between two containers instead of using
>   --link. One feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with --link is sharing environmental variables between
>   containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to
>   share environment variables between containers in a more controlled
>   way.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/