# How do I link containers in a docker compose file (docker-compose.yml)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am not able to link MySQL and play containers using docker compose. See the yml file below:

```
zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4
    ports:
       - 2181:2181
kafka:
    image: ches/kafka:latest
    ports:
       - 9092:9092
    links: 
       - zookeeper
myDpm:
    image: dpm-image:latest
    ports:
       - 9000:9000
    links:
       - kafka
       - zookeeper
mySql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
myMc3:
    image: mc3-v3:3.0
    ports:
        - 9001:9000
    links:
        - mySql:3306  
    environment:
       runMode: dev
myElastic:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.0
    ports:
        - 9200:9200
```

I want to link mysql with my play scala project. I am getting an error:

> [error] - [play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler] - Cannot invoke the action
>   java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 10001ms of waiting for a
>   connection.   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227)
>   ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182)
>   ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93)
>   ~[com.zaxxer.HikariCP-java6-2.3.7.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:12)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick-hikaricp_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]    at
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:414)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:297)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:407)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:33)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.iteratorTo(StatementInvoker.scala:22)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:48)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.firstOption(Invoker.scala:24)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.firstOption(StatementInvoker.scala:16)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadOptionAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:57)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.jdbc.StreamingInvokerAction$HeadOptionAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:56)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
>   ~[com.typesafe.slick.slick_2.11-3.1.1.jar:na]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111] Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

Answer (score 10):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173670/are-docker-links-deprecated) docker links are somewhat replaced by networks.

> Before the Docker network feature, you could use the Docker link feature to allow containers to discover each other. With the introduction of Docker networks, containers can be discovered by its name automatically.

By default all containers in a compose file join a default network (if no other network is defined) and you should be able to access one service from another service by using the servicename and the right port such as: mySql:3306

More information can be found in the [network docs from docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: This phrase solved my issue "you should be able to access one service from another service by using the *servicename*"

Answer (score 1):

Link correctly to MySQL:

```
myMc3:
  ...
  links:
    - mySql
```

(Without the 3306)

Answer (score -1):

If mc3-v3:3.0 need mysql container then you will use depends on to solve dependency.It will first run mysql then mc3..

And make sure that in mc3-v3 you use mysql:3306 in code to connect mysql or use mysql container ip for connection.

```
myMc3:
image: mc3-v3:3.0
ports:
    - 9001:9000
depends:
    - mySql
environment:
   runMode: dev
```