# can't acces mongo from inside docker

Tags: java, mongodb, docker

I'm trying to access `mongo` from inside of a `docker container`
The error occurs when I'm trying to create the `connection`.

`new MongoClient(host, port)`is working.

`mongo` is also running in a `docker container` and I was able to connect to it with `robomongo` and also running the app outside its `docker container` can connect do `mongo`

I'm getting following exception

```
No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=172.17.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}


2017-05-25T21:11:32.277  INFO 5 --- [72.17.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 172.17.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
... 3 common frames omitted
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
mongo:
 image: library/mongo:3.4.4
 ports: 
   - "27017:27017"
   - "28017:28017"
   - "28018:28018"
 volumes:
   - ./data/mongo:/data/db

dronedelivery:
  image: paulcurcean/dronedelivery:latest
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

**Dockerfile for dronedelivery**

```
ADD dronedelivery-0-SNAPSHOT.jar /
ADD start.sh /  # java -jar dronedelivery-0-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["sh", "/start.sh"]
```

**docker ps / docker-compose ps**

```
image                 ports
dronedelivery         0.0.0.0:8080 -> 8080/tcp
mongo                 0.0.0.0:27017 -> 27017/tcp, 0.0.0.0:28017-28018 -> 28017-28018/tcp
```

I'm connecting to `mongo` via `new MongoClient(host, port)`

Comment: please add the `docker-compose.yml` or the corresponding `Dockerfile`s.

Comment: Can you also give information how you connect to the container?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem you are encountering is due to the fact that you are referencing the host incorrectly.

I created a working [POC here](https://github.com/omacarena/only-short-poc/tree/master/java.spring.mongo) in order create two containers, a SpringBoot application container and the Mongo container. The information and instructions are in the `README.md`.

There are multiple points which may cause your app to malfunction:

- you might need to ensure that your app should run after Mongo is functioning properly
- your containers are by default connected to the default `bridge` network which is a separate network than the host network (your actual main network). The `bridge` network is connected to your main host network. Therefore referencing one container from another container needs to be done in respect to the network used to connect the containers, thus the `bridge` network.
- having in `docker-compose.yml` - `services.mymongo` with ports `12345:27017` means that the Mongo database can be referred to from another container as `mymongo:27017` but from host like `localhost:12345`. Using from another container `localhost:27017` is incorrect because `mymongo` is one host and `myapp` for example is another. Calling `localhost` from `myapp` does not mean `mymongo` host.
- in order to query the health of your Mongo instance you can enable the REST api using `mongod --rest`. Thus `command: ["mongod", "--rest"]` in `docker-compose.yml`. This is used when starting the app container in order to know if the Mongo instance is up and running.

**Sample `docker-compose.yml`:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    build: ./myapp/docker
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mymongo:27017/mydb
      - MONGODB_STATUS_HOST=mymongo
      - MONGODB_STATUS_PORT=28017
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
  mymongo:
    image: mongo:3.4
    volumes:
      - ./_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 12345:27017
      - 23456:28017
    command: ["mongod", "--rest"]
```

Notice that Mongo is configured on port `27017` and thus the REST interface will be available on `27017 + 1000 = 28017`.

**Sample app Dockerfile**

The following is the Dockerfile for creating the image of the app that connects to the Mongo instance:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/myapp
ADD ./myapp.jar /usr/local/myapp/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

Then the app is started with the following `run.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Wait for mongodb to be available"
echo "********************************************************"

while ! nc -z $MONGODB_STATUS_HOST $MONGODB_STATUS_PORT; do
  printf 'mongodb is still not available. Retrying...\n'
  sleep 3
done

echo "********************************************************"
echo "Starting myapp"
echo "********************************************************"

java -Dserver.port=$SERVER_PORT \
     -Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=$MONGODB_URI \
     -jar /usr/local/myapp/myapp.jar
```

Notice that it first waits for the Mongo instance to start by querying its REST interface and just after that it uses the OpenJdk 8 JRE to start the app from its `.jar` file.

Comment: I can't how I'm referring the host incorrectly, because with the same referring I could connect with 'robomongo' and also the app could connect when running outside the docker container.

Comment: @Paul from outside of your container you might access it like `mongo://localhost:27017/...` but from inside you might do it like `mongo://mongo:27017/...`.

Comment: @Paul there are two different networks, the one from your host, and the one where containers are connected - the default, `bridge` as it is called. Think of them as separate networks with a little wire between them to allow you to access the containers also on your host.

Comment: @Paul so containers are like having two PCs joined on a network. You want to connect to the PC with mongo from PC with dronedelivery. Thus you will connect to PC with mongo with `mongo://mongo:27017`.

Comment: my mongo container runs on a digitalocean server and I could connect to it from my local pc -> the connection from inside docker to mongo should be the same as from my local pc to mongo. Also the app running on my local pc can connect to mongo.

Comment: @Paul I haven't used DigitalOcean, but I think is the same thing. Try to connect inside the container network with host=mongo and port=27017. It seems that more is written [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-docker-ecosystem-networking-and-communication).

Answer (score 1):

You could use docker-compose instead.

First, install [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

I assume you are using a Dockerfile for your application.

Create a directory with a **docker-compose.yml** inside.

```
version: '2'
services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always

  app:
    build: ./app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./_client/:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Now, in ./app put your current Dockerfile for the application.

In a _client/ folder put your app (you can correct the internal path /var/www/html as you need). Both folders in the same level as docker-compose.yml file.

Finally, run all with docker-compose:

`docker-compose -f /path/to/your/docker-compose.yml build`

This command will build the image from your Dockerfile

`docker-compose -f /path/to/your/docker-compose.yml up`

This command will create and run all defined containers.

To access your mongodb container from inside the app container, you can use "mongo" as hostname (same name defined in "services:"). From your host machine, you can use the docker container IP, but you need to expose a port, same way as "app" service in the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: You have `links:` twice

Comment: [`links` is legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173670/are-docker-links-deprecated). You should use `networks` or/and [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode) instead to configure how the containers are connected. There are a number of predefined networks `bridge`, `host`, `none`. The default is `bridge`, therefore all containers can see each other with no problems. I think the problem stands in other aspect.

Comment: @andreim Thank you very much, my problem has been solved